# Prove square root of 16 is rational

Tags: rational-numbers, square-numbers

I am student and i understand that the square root of any perfect square is a rational number but i'am trying to prove it (e.g for 16).

Comment: $\sqrt {16}= 4$ which is rational.  Done..... Seriously.  that's *all* you have to do.

Comment: "that any perfect square number is a rational number"  Well, every integer is a rational number (because an integer $k = \frac k1$; a ratio of two integers).  And a perfect square is a square of an integer.  So it's an integer times an integer and is thus an integer itself.  .... I think you are assuming mathematics is harder than it actually is.

Comment: And by *definition* if $k$ is a non-negative integer then $\sqrt{k^2} =k$ which is an integer and therefore rational...... MUCH, MUCH, Harder is prove that if $n$ is a positive integer and $n$ is *NOT* a perfect square the $\sqrt n$ is *not* rational.  But the converse.  If $n=k^2$ *is* a perfect square then $\sqrt{n} =\sqrt{k^2} = |k|$ is basic. ... it's not *supposed* to be hard.

Comment: The square root of a perfect square is, by definition, an integer.

Comment: Claim:  If $n=m^2$ is a perfect square then $\sqrt n$ is rational.  Pf:  $\sqrt n=\sqrt{m^2} =|m|$ which is a (rational) integer.  Done.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

As the other commentors and answerer have noted, this is essentially by definition, but if you'd like something that looks perhaps more "mathematical":  suppose that $m = n^2$ where $n\in {\mathbb Z}$ is a perfect square and suppose that its square root is *not* rational.  Then there must exist $p \in {\mathbb Z}$ and $q\in {\mathbb N}$ such that 
$$ \left| \sqrt{m} - \frac{p}{q} \right| > 0$$
If that ever equalled zero then we'd have found a rational number that was the square root of $m$, and we're claiming we can't do that.
Since $\sqrt{m} = n$ because $m$ is a perfect square, we have
$$ \left| n - \frac{p}{q} \right| > 0$$
for *all* $p,q$.  In particular, this must hold when $q=1$, i.e.
$$ \left| n - \frac{p}{1} \right| > 0$$
But $n$ and $p$ both lie in $\mathbb Z$ so we can take $p=n$, which is a contradiction.  So our hypothesis that the square root of $m$ was not rational must have been false.

Answer (score 1):

How can it not be?

By definition a perfect square is a square of an integer.

And by definition the square root of a number is the non-negative number which the number of is a square of.

And since a perfect square is the square of an integer, the number it is  square of is an integer.

And all integers are rational.